# What's difference for below phrases and words

Tags: word-usage

What are the differences in the following phrases:

1. engage in
2. work on
3. commit oneself to
4. dedicate oneself to

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but I'm guessing that to "commite oneselfe" is to press the shutter button on the camera attached to your selfie stick.

Comment: What's with the medieval spelling, though? Just curious.

Comment: Mike, I've fixed your spelling and reformatted your question according to my lights.  If I've misrepresented what you wanted to ask, you may reject my edits.  My changes have left Hot Licks' comment and Ricky's question without their original context.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Engage in* means to participate in some activity.
2. *Work on* means to contribute effort to some activity.

Engaging is slightly more general, as it includes things that don't take much effort:

> He **engaged in** light banter while he **worked on** fixing the flat
>   tire.

3. *To commit oneself to* something means to pledge one's support and effort.
4. *To dedicate oneself to* means to devote (i.e, set aside) time, energy, or other personal resources to some cause:

> Since he had **dedicated himself to** the cause of animal welfare,
>   **he committed himself to** raising $10,000 for the local animal shelter.

You may dedicate yourself to something privately, but a commitment is usually a pledge made to and known by others.

One person may do all four of these simultaneously with respect to some activity, but the four verbs describe different aspects of the effort.

Answer (score 0):

If you engage in something, you are involved in it.
" I engaged in my project".

If you work on something, you produce or repair it.
" I work on my car = I repair my car".
" I can not spend time this week to work on my novel".

If you commit yourself to doing something, you bind or obligate yourself to do it.
" I commit myself to leading my family".

If you dedicate yourself to something, you pay your attention and efforts to it.
" I dedicate myself to my goal".